# Is that possible to pass a variable to route files like api.php to use as a middleware's name?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to use "Laratrust" package for manage permissions in my project.

in laratrust can define middlewares like this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['role:admin']], function() {
    Route::get('dashboard/posts', 'posts@pagesController');
}
```

I want to have a route inside a middleware, inside another  middleware like this:

```
Route::middleware('mainMiddleware')->group(function ($role) {
    Route::group(["middleware" => ["role:$role"]], function () {
        Route::get('dashboard/posts', 'posts@pagesController');
    });
});
```

What I want is: pass the $role variable created in "mainMiddleware" to the route and use as a middleware name. is there any way I can do that?

Comment: That sounds to me like some logic belonging to a controller.

Comment: You should not really "create" a role inside a middleware. Why do you want/need to do this?

Comment: @MatthiasS I don't create the role inside the middleware. the role already exists in database. but the role name depends on some variable  based on user's cookie

Comment: Simply you can add a custom header in your top level middleware and access it via request object of router and pass it to sub-level middleware

Answer (score 1):

You may be need new middleware.. i made sample if this is meet with your needs

```
class CheckRoleMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        //get current user role
        $role = get_current_user_role(); //sample only
        if (Auth::user()->hasRole($role)) {
            return $next($request);
        }


        return error_message() //sample only
    }
}
```